# How to make a lazycolumn scroll to the end when using bottomsheetscaffold?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I am going to design a layout with a bottomsheetscaffold with sheetPeekHeight to be 100 dp in order to show the sheet content. I also need to put a lazyColumn for the main content of the bottomsheetscaffold. But when the lazy column scrolls to the end, the final item will be behind the bottom sheet. How can I make the final item of the column be above the sheet?

Here is the code for the bottom sheet:

```
    @ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {

    val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState = BottomSheetState(BottomSheetValue.Collapsed)
    )
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    
    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
            Text("this is test", modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(60.dp))
        },
        sheetPeekHeight = 100.dp,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topEnd = 52.dp, topStart = 52.dp),
        backgroundColor = Color.White
    ) {
        MainContent()
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainContent() {
    LazyColumn {
        items(count = 5) { itemIndex ->
            when (itemIndex) {
                0 -> {
                    Image(modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(100.dp), contentDescription = "test",
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.image))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any img or code??

Comment: I will add codes

Comment: You can use contentPadding parameter to give bottom padding to LazyColumn items.

Answer (score 1):

`Spacer(modifier=Modifier.height(100.dp))` I think fits better than a box here.

In your case it is easier to use fixed height, but if your content is dynamic you can also calculate bottomSheet height based on screenheight - bottomSheetOffset

```
fun YourComposable{
...
    val bottomSheetHeight =
        configuration.screenHeightDp.dp - bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.offset.value.pxToDp
...
}

private val Float.pxToDp: Dp
    get() = (this / Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).dp
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I added an empty box with the same height as peekheight to the end of the lazycloumn. But I'm still interested in a better solution.